# VB.NET CreateObject dll ambiguity

Tags: vb.net, dll, ambiguity, createobject

could you please help with the following

I try to use Some.dll version 5.0 within my code.
However, Excel has multiple reference for the same dll, with earlier versions like 4.0
If I run:

```
Set co = CreateObject("SomeClass.Object")
```

even if I created a reference in Tools->References for the newest Some.dll, it calls one of the oldest dll, that does not have some functionality.

I do not have admin right to change registry, remove programs from my computer.

Is it possible somehow set reference to the newest version dll?

I tried:

```
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32"...
lb = LoadLibrary(C:\somepath\Some.dll) ' lb is the 5.0 version dll that should be used
set co = CreateObject("lb.Object")
```

however, it is not working ("ActiveX... can't create object")

and looked through all the net, but could not find advise, how to create object with a specific dll path.

Please help, thanks: Jim

Answer (score 3):

I could find sollution inbetween,

it is a function called CreateObjectFromFile() that helps.

```
CreateObjectFromFile("C:\somepath\Some.dll", "SomeClass")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same problem, and solved it this way:

Reference to old version:

```
Set co = CreateObject("SomeClass.Object.4.0")
```

Reference to new version:

```
Set co = CreateObject("SomeClass.Object.5.0")
```